# MPI to read all files in a directory

Tags: c++, c, mpi

Hi guys I am learning to program in MPI and I came across this question. 
Lets say that the current working directory I have 10 files. Each file contains a column with numbers. 
I want to divide the work among all processors, so for example if i use, say, two nodes, i want node 1 to read the first 5 files and the second node do the rest.
Thank you for any help.

Comment: This rather falls into system programming than MPI itself, see some `readdir` examples.

Comment: Expect to be disappointed when you find that processes waste more time contending for a single i/o channel than they save by distributing the work.  Unless, that is, you have a distributed file system and the hardware to permit different nodes accessing different files by different routes.

Answer (score 1):

There are no metadata operations in MPI-IO aside from open/create a file or deleting that file.   I suppose it was hard to standardize over windows, unix, and, I don't know.. vax-y styles back in the old days?

The nice thing about MPI is that it provides a good basis for libraries.  Write a "MPI-IO metadata" library... and share it with us!